# Enterprise Architect user interface diagram checked checkbox

Tags: user-interface, checkbox, uml, enterprise-architect

How to make my checkbox on user interface diagram checked? I'm using Enterprise Architect 11.

edit: It's checkbox left control which I put on Screen control. It's all on user interface diagram.

Comment: Where does this checkbox exist?

Comment: The question is how to check programmatically the UIControl element checkbox?

Comment: The question is how to add "checked tick" to this checkbox control

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the experience to help you. A good advice is to try ask EA questions in a dedicated forum : http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controls in the User Interface toolbox do not include state information, so you can't set a checkbox to be checked or otherwise, either in EA's GUI or through the API.

The controls in the Simple User Interface toolbox do include state information as tagged values; the checkbox state is represented by the tagged value `Value` (Checked/Unchecked/Mixed).

There's no corresponding Simple User Interface diagram, but you can select the toolbox using the More Tools button at the top of the toolbox windows.

So if you create a simpleUI::simpleCheckBox, search its `Element.TaggedValues` collection to find the one named Value and change its `Value` field to Checked.

Answer (score -1):

that no worky.
Create a label.
Put a lowercase x in it.
And then superimpose it on the unchecked box.
It worked for me.
[image]